# Mapping a pair to a struct

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap

There's some code I've written which I have trouble with, but I've tried to write a simplified version of it to possibly reproduce the error I'm encountering:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct test{
    float y;
};

typedef pair<int, int> intpair;
map<intpair, test> mp;

void func(test &obj){
    obj.y = 23.5;
}



int main () {
   test* obj = new test;
   auto key = make_pair(1,1);
   mp.insert(key, obj);
   func(*obj);
   //cout << *(obj->y);
   delete obj;
   return 0;
}
```

What I would like to do is map a `pair` to a custom `struct test` that I have created. I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:22:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map, test>::insert(std::pair&, test*&)’
    mp.insert(key, obj);
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/map:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/stdc++.h:81,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:731:7: note: candidate: std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Allocator>::rebind >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = std::pair; _Tp = test; _Compare = std::less >; _Alloc = std::allocator, test> >; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Allocator>::rebind >::other>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator, test> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair, test>]
       insert(const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:731:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:739:9: note: candidate: template std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Allocator>::rebind >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_Pair&&) [with _Pair = _Pair;  = ; _Key = std::pair; _Tp = test; _Compare = std::less >; _Alloc = std::allocator, test> >]
         insert(_Pair&& __x)
         ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:739:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:22:22: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
    mp.insert(key, obj);
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/map:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/stdc++.h:81,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:752:7: note: candidate: void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::initializer_list >) [with _Key = std::pair; _Tp = test; _Compare = std::less >; _Alloc = std::allocator, test> >]
       insert(std::initializer_list<value_type> __list)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:752:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:781:7: note: candidate: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, const value_type&) [with _Key = std::pair; _Tp = test; _Compare = std::less >; _Alloc = std::allocator, test> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator, test> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator, test> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair, test>]
       insert(const_iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:781:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair’ to ‘std::map, test>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator, test> >}’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:792:9: note: candidate: template std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Pair&&) [with _Pair = _Pair;  = ; _Key = std::pair; _Tp = test; _Compare = std::less >; _Alloc = std::allocator, test> >]
         insert(const_iterator __position, _Pair&& __x)
         ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:792:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:22:22: note:   cannot convert ‘key’ (type ‘std::pair’) to type ‘std::map, test>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator, test> >}’
    mp.insert(key, obj);
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/map:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/stdc++.h:81,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:807:9: note: candidate: template void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _Key = std::pair; _Tp = test; _Compare = std::less >; _Alloc = std::allocator, test> >]
         insert(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
         ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:807:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:22:22: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_InputIterator’ (‘std::pair’ and ‘test*’)
    mp.insert(key, obj);
```

Also, I'm sure that I'm going wrong in the way I access my `obj`'s member y (cout statement commented out); How do I go about resolving these issues?

Comment: Ask youself, In `map<intpair, test> mp`, what is the type of the key-value pair.  Does the type of `object` match that type?

Comment: intpair basically is an alias for pair<int, int>, and I'm mapping it to an instance of the struct created (which should be *obj).  I think I'm still missing something

Comment: You should use ```mp.insert(make_pair(key, *obj))``` as insert expects a pair of ```intpair``` and ```test``` (not a pointer as in your code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no overload of [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) that takes a key and a value.

You can use [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) to add a new element:

```
   mp[key] = *obj;
```

Or [`std::map::insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) since C++17:

```
   mp.insert_or_assign(key, *obj);
```

Another point is that type of `obj` is `test*` while the type of values of the map `mp` has type `test`. The pointer should be dereferenced (like my examples above) or the type of values should be changed to pointers to do this insertion.

Comment: That worked! I have a couple of follow up questions though:
1) How do I access ```obj```'s member? I tried ```cout << *(obj->y)```, but that throws up an error.
2) Right now, I delete the ```obj``` pointer. Will deleting the entry from the map remove ```obj``` from the memory as well? (I believe it'll not, but how do I delete it?). Right now I've tried something like

```delete mp[key]; mp.erase(key);```

Comment: 1) `cout << *(obj->y)` won't work because `obj->y` is not a pointer. It should be `cout << obj->y;` or `cout << (*obj).y;`. 2) Deleting `obj` won't delete elements in the map because a copy of `*obj` is stored if the type of the map isn't changed. `mp.erase(key);` will do deletion of what is stored in the map. Or what are stored in map will be deleted on deletion of map (returning from `main()` in this case).

Comment: Right. So what I intend to do is first free up my memory which contains ```obj```, and then delete the entry from the map so that there's no memory leak. But let's say, the catch is that I have access only to the ```key```, and I intend to delete/erase using ```mp[key]``` only. I'm a little bit stuck there, because ```delete mp[key]``` will only delete ```*obj``` here, I think. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: `delete mp[key]` is invalid because `mp[key]` (`test`) is not a pointer.

Comment: Don't use `new` here because I don't think it is required. Statically allocate an object of `test`. Trust freeing system of `std::map` and the stack.